# Using '|' as delimitting regular expression(regex) in split() method in Java

Tags: java, split, escaping

I have a String named s;

```
s="abc|def|ghi";
```

I have tried to split s using regex "|" so that I get ["abc","def","ghi"].

```
s.split("|");
```

But instead I got ["a","b","c","|","d",...].

But when I used "\\|" as regex,that is:

```
s.split("\\|");
```

and I got desired output.
Can anyone please explain the reason behind it? And is it valid (I mean, not a compiler dependent) operation?

Comment: You answered your own question, didn't you? The argument to String.split is regex.

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't understand. Using regex as ":","-" works. Then why not "|"?

Comment: `|` is the regex metacharacter for alternation. [`X|Y` means match either X or Y](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#logical). In this case, that means match either nothing or nothing, and use that as the thing to split upon. Since "nothing" matches in the gap between every character, you get an array of every character.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But in the next case, does it matches a backslash or nothing?

Comment: Neither. The string literal `"\\|"` in Java source is interpreted by the compiler as the string `\|`, and that is then passed to String.split and interpreted by the regex engine as matching a literal `|`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have now understood all the cases. And sorry for this silly question.

Comment: If you wanted to split on \ instead of `|`, you'd have to write `.split("\\\\")` because the is the string value of \\ which then has the meaning of a literal \ for the regex engine. \ is escape character for both and needs to be escaped for both in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java strings, the '\' mark is used as escape character. So if you want to get the '\' itself, you need to use an '\' to an escape character and then '\' itself as you know "\"
so

```
String str = "\\";
```

the str is an string with only one "\".

And the '\' mark is also used as escape character in regular expressions. So

```
String str = "\\|";
```

the str is an string with "\|" and it represents "|" itself in regular expressions.
So you could get desired output.

Comment: For the first case, this should be added (From the comment of Boann)-"| is the regex metacharacter for alternation. X|Y means match either X or Y. In this case, that means match either nothing or nothing, and use that as the thing to split upon. Since "nothing" matches in the gap between every character, you get an array of every character."